# how to map with JSON a property from object

Tags: java, json, annotations, jackson, playframework-2.2

Im writing a web app using play freamwork,
i have the following class:

```
public class Project{
   string name
   Image image
}
```

image class

```
public class Image{
  String path;
  String na,e;
  int x;
  int y;
}
```

i want to serialize Project so i get the path when serializing (not the whole image object) :

i.e.:

```
{ "name" : proj_name, "image" : "path" }
```

I think this can be done via annotations, but could not find the correct one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to write custom deserializer, which writes only path property to JSON:

```
class ImagePathJsonSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Image> {

    @Override
    public void serialize(Image image, JsonGenerator jsonGenerator,
            SerializerProvider serializerProvider) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        jsonGenerator.writeString(image.path);
    }
}
```

Now, you can use `@JsonSerialize` annotation:

```
class Project {
    private String name;

    @JsonSerialize(using = ImagePathJsonSerializer.class)
    private Image image;

    //getters, setters
}
```